# Swatches setting

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, swatches

My stroke panel doesn't have the same swatches as my fill panel and I am trying to update it. For some reason it has imported some pattern swatches I made but when I try to import the Basic RGB swatch from the swatches library menu it pops up in a different window.

[image]

[image]

This is what I see when I open the stroke panel

[image: Stroke Panel]

This is what I see when I open the fill panel

[image: Fill panel]

Answer (score 1):

There was a setting it was on to show patterned swatches only and I switched it back to show all swatches. All fixed now! >_<

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just select them all and drag them into the main swatches panel.

You can click on the first one and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click on the last one and then Click+Drag into the main swatches panel.

Comment: I dragged RGB swatches to main swatches panel and it has updated  the fill swatch panel but not the stroke swatch panel?

Comment: @user3413128 there i sno such thing as a stroke swatch panel.

Comment: @user3413128 it looks like you are using the dropout swatches panel, instead use the actual *Swatches* panel (**Window → Swatches**)

Comment: What is the stroke panel at the top of the window then? I know there is more than one way of accessing the swatches panel through the side tool bar and the top panel in stroke and fill however the stroke panel at the moment has no colour swatches which is odd because it usually replicates the same as the fill. There are a couple of pattern swatches I created in the stroke panel for some reason. I'll add an image comparing stroke and fill panels